# Recursively creating a JSON tree, adding only at the deepest level

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to create a JSON hierarchy structure of unknown objects, so it must be handled recursively.

Here's my function, where `angular.element.isEmptyObject()` is inherited from jQuery, and `angular.copy()` is a function that creates a deep copy of the object (I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)).

```
function recurseTree(tree, newKey, newId) {
    if(angular.element.isEmptyObject(tree)) {
        tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
    } else {
        for(var key in tree) {
            if(typeof tree[key] == 'object') recurseTree(tree[key], newKey, newId);
            else tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
        }
    }
    return angular.copy(tree);
}
```

Now run this:

```
var testT = {};
console.log(recurseTree(testT, 'a', '1'));
console.log(recurseTree(testT, 'b', '2'));
console.log(recurseTree(testT, 'c', '3'));
console.log(recurseTree(testT, 'd', '4'));
console.log(recurseTree(testT, 'e', '5'));
```

You'll notice that the first and second ones return as expected:

```
{ 
    a: { 
        _id: '1',
        b: {
            _id: '2'
        }
    }
}
```

but the third one is where I run into trouble.

```
{ 
    a: { 
        _id: '1',
        b: {
            _id: '2',
            c: {
                _id: '3'
            }
        },
        c: {
            _id: '3'
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to fix to get the `c` object appended **ONLY** as a child of `b`, rather than also as a child of `a`?  I'm stumped.

Here's a JSFiddle of it in action, check your console for the results.  http://jsfiddle.net/winduptoy/Mjq5D/2/

Comment: Can you put together a working http://jsfiddle.net with all of the dependent libraries?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I forgot one, I added it to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function recurseTree(tree, newKey, newId) {
    if(angular.element.isEmptyObject(tree)) {
        tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
        return;
    } 

    var child = null; // find current tree's child
    for(var key in tree) {
        if (key != '_id') {
            child = tree[key]; // found a child
            break;
        }
    }
    if (child) { // recursively process on child
        recurseTree(child, newKey, newId);
    } else { // no child, so just fill the tree
        tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var testT = {};
recurseTree(testT, 'a', '1');
console.log(testT);  
recurseTree(testT, 'b', '1');
console.log(testT); 
recurseTree(testT, 'c', '1');
console.log(testT); 
recurseTree(testT, 'd', '1');
console.log(testT); 
recurseTree(testT, 'e', '1');
console.log(testT);
```

Please be noted that I have not used `angular.copy(tree)` for the performance's sake.
If you don't want to change the tree, copy it before passing it to the function `recurseTree`. Please try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzheng/tsV2X/).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is correct.  You have also solved another one of my questions.  If you will also post this code here, I will accept your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088181/recursively-creating-a-json-tree-structure-from-arrays-of-objects#comment19483848_14088181

Comment: You're very welcome, and I answered that question as per your request.

Answer (score 1):

have a try? is it necessary to use `for loop` ?

```
for(var key in tree) {
   if(typeof tree[key] == 'object'){ 
       recurseTree(tree[key], newKey, newId);
       break;
   }
   else {
       tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Adding the `break`s in there fixed it, but can you explain how I can  do it without the for loop?

Comment: @WindUpToy at the situation you posted, new node was always added to  the first-child-node at that tree level. so I said it is unnecessary to use `for loop`.

Comment: Hui is correct, this isn't exactly right.  His code is now the accepted answer.

Comment: `@HuiZheng`, `@Wind Up Toy` I just find  out the logical error, and posted it before a test, if any better answer, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
vm.getChilds = function (data, parent_id) {
        return _.filter(data, function (item) {
            return item.parent_id == parent_id;
        });
    };
    vm.getIds = function (arr) {
        var ids = [];
        arr.forEach(function (item) {
            ids.push(item.id);
        });
        return ids;
    };
    vm.updateList = function (data, arr) {
        var ids = vm.getIds(arr);
        var result = [];
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            if (ids.indexOf(item.id) == -1) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
    vm.getThree = function (data, parent_id) {
        var items = vm.getChilds(data, parent_id);
        if (items.length == 0) return null;
        var tree = [];
        var newData = vm.updateList(data, items);
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            item.sub_departments = vm.getThree(newData, item.id);
            tree.push(item);
        });
        return tree;
    };
```