# Recursively creating a JSON tree structure from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

Here is my data structure:

```
{ projects: [
      { revisions: [
            { files: [] },
        ],
      }
  ],
  user: {}
}
```

Go to the jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/winduptoy/EXdDy/

I'm tyring to recursively create a JSON hierarchy structure of an object's parents and their `id`s.  Check your console.  Look at `projects[0].revisions[0]._idTree`, which contains the `projects._id` and `revisions` as a ***child*** of `projects`, just as expected.  Now look at `projects[0].revisions[0].files[0]._idTree`, which contains `projects.files` as a ***sibling*** of `projects.revisions`, when `files` should be a ***child*** of `projects.revisions`.  How do I fix this?

Comment: you never change newKey, and newId parameters that you pass to the recurseTree function.

Comment: Are you sure?  I think I do.  Look two lines down, I recursively call `attachIDs(data[key][item], ...)` in itself, so in the second recursive call, `data` is actually `data[key][item]`.

Comment: I mean inside the body of recurseTree it calls itself recursively with the same second and third parameters.

Comment: That's correct.  If `tree[key]` is an object, I want to keep going to the deepest level of that object before I apply `newKey` and `newId`, it seems like that shouldn't matter, since those are just the new properties I *will* be applying.

Comment: Looks like the problem was with how I was dealing with my `recurseTree()` function.  Hui Zheng posted a better version here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087914/recursively-creating-a-json-tree-adding-only-at-the-deepest-level/14088259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rewrite `recurseTree` like this:

```
function recurseTree(tree, newKey, newId) {
    if(angular.element.isEmptyObject(tree)) {
        tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
        return;
    } 

    var child = null; // find current tree's child
    for(var key in tree) {
        if (key != '_id') {
            child = tree[key]; // found a child
            break;
        }
    }
    if (child) { // recursively process on child
        recurseTree(child, newKey, newId);
    } else { // no child, so just fill the tree
        tree[newKey] = {_id: newId};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you should be using:

http://www.jstree.com/